# How can I use prepend properly?

Tags: javascript, prepend

I'm trying to make it so when I go to a specific website, it will put some text on the screen.

I've tried using different ways to format the code using 'prepend' None of this actually worked.

```js
if (window.location.href.indexOf("https://play.google.com/store") !== -1 || window.location){
    $('body').prepend('
    <div id="_security">
    <h2>TextTop</h2>
        <p>TextBottom</p>
    </div>')
}
```

The result is that the file doesn't run.

Error:

```
Line: 2
Char: 24
Code: 800A03F7
Source: Microsoft JScript compilation error
```

Comment: Inside `' '` you can't have `\n` newlines. Use` instead.

Comment: JavaScript doesn't allow newlines in string constants.

Comment: Changing to a template literal (e.g. `\` ... \`` instead of `' ... '`) will fix this issue, as these allow line-breaks within the code itself.

Comment: In what environment are you running this? Microsoft JScript is not the same as normal JavaScript.

Comment: I've changed to (` code `) instead, and I still get the same error.

Comment: I'm running this in vscode, and then running it by clicking on the JSFile.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot add multiple lines without concatenating.
Here is the correct way:

```
$(function(){
    if (window.location.href.indexOf("https://play.google.com/store") !== -1 || window.location){
        $('body').prepend('<div id="_security"><h2>TextTop</h2><p>TextBottom</p></div>')
    }
});
```

You can do with concatenate:

```
$('body').prepend(
    '<div id="_security">'+
    '<h2>TextTop</h2>'+
    '<p>TextBottom</p>'+
    '</div>');
```

Comment: It now asks for an object, how do I go about this, I'm new to JS.

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is not only the line breaks.Is also that you are running your code with the default environment of windows which does not support the host-provided objects like `window` and `document`.Consider running your code in a browser adding a `<script>` tag to an HTML document or paste the code into the web console.